# jQuery JSON search engine within tags

Tags: jquery, json, search, tags

I love Font-Awesome, but sometimes search for the right icon is such a pain: i.e. there is no "fa-help" icon, but I have to remember that is "fa-question"; no "fa-magnifying-glass" or "fa-view", but "fa-search", and so on. Searching the right icon is often a waste of time.

Here comes an idea: a JSON-based search engine where I put a term (or tag) and the right icon(s) are returned. I.e., given this JSON:

```
{

    "fa-camera": [
        "camera",
        "picture",
        "image"
    ],
    "fa-camera-retro": [
        "camera",
        "retro",
        "picture",
        "image"
    ],
    "fa-check": [
        "check",
        "tick",
        "approve",
        "ok"
    ]

}
```

searching for "tick" or "approve" should return "fa-check"; searching for "picture" should return "fa-camera" and "fa-camera-retro" (and any other icon associated with the tag "picture"), and so on.

Of course it would be nice also to enter a part of the tag (i.e. "pic") and have the right icon(s) displayed while typing, as a sort of autocomplete feature: but maybe I'm going too further :-)

I can easily do this with MySQL and PHP, but I'm not so equally confident in jQuery and, apart creating the form, I don't know where to start; more specifically, I don't know how to search into the JSON for the tag to return the corresponding icons

Please, any help? Is there a clear tutorial, or a jQuery plugin for this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't really need jquery for this, simple JS. Here's a possible solution. I'm sure it can be optimised though. Good luck!

```
var db = {

    "fa-camera": [
        "camera",
        "picture",
        "image"
    ],
    "fa-camera-retro": [
        "camera",
        "retro",
        "picture",
        "image"
    ],
    "fa-check": [
        "check",
        "tick",
        "approve",
        "ok"
    ]

};

function searchTags(tag){
    var response = [];
    if(db instanceof Object)   
    {
        for(j in db)
        {
            var tags = db[j];
            for(var i=0; i<tags.length; i++)
            {
                if(tags[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(tag) != -1) //you can improve this by using a regular expression
                {
                    response.push(j);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Please define a db object");
    }

    return response;
}

var tag = prompt("Enter a tag you want to search for", "");

alert("Findings: " + searchTags(tag).join());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y715vbgd/

Comment: Thank you, you pointed me in the right direction and I'm adding improvements! :-) I'll share the search engine on GitHub (and maybe I'll ask for a code review before) when it's done